# Handling exceptions from service layer applying clean code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a service that saves an employee, if the employee email or code already exists the service return an Exception that is catched in the controller and then add the error to return the view. I'm starting practicing clean code, and I want to know if this implementation is fine or if the `service.Save(e)` method should validate if email/code exists and just return a status code.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Employee e)
    {

          if (ModelState.IsValid)
          {
            try
            {
              service.Save(e);
              RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (EmailExistException ex)
            {
              ModelState.AddModelError("email", ex.Message);
            }
            catch (CodeExistException ex)
            {
              ModelState.AddModelError("code", ex.Message);
            }


          }

          return View(e);
    }
```

Comment: Having an email that already exists isn't really an exception but rather a business rules. You need a way to combine business rules and display multiple to the user. Right now, only one can be displayed at a time. The save should fail but you'll need an other way to get the errors. It could be something like service.GetBusinessRuleErrors(). you could even have a service.AreBusinessRuleValid() before calling the save.

Comment: Agree with the_lotus. Or you could make service.Save return a `SaveResult` which indicates success or failure with reason. This question is opinion based though, so not suitable for SO.

Comment: I agree with @the_lotus - don't throw "business logic exceptions". You're much better off reserving exceptions for things that can't happen if your application is being used normally. The main reasons are that catching and rethrowing exceptions gets messy real fast, it's hard to do useful stuff in a `catch` anyway, your code gets cluttered with Exception classes, and you can only throw one thing at a time. Validation logic can be an important part of your business layer. I tend to return container objects with a payload property and an `IsSuccessful` flag or maybe an error list.